# Lining up columns using awk

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I'm trying to use awk to pull every 9th column out of a dataset with 210 columns. How can I get the columns to line up evenly if the data in each column do not contain the same number of characters?

Comment: Is it important for you to do this in awk and write, to standard output, something that will look lined up when rendered in a fixed-width font?  If not, just write out your data with awk, quoted and comma-separated, and open it up in a spreadsheet program and print it from there. :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try that :)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - in awk, you don't need to line up the input columns, you just need to properly define which regular expression can be used to separate them.

Comment: can you make an example? I don't understand the requirement well....

Answer (score 0):

Use `for loop` to skip over the column you don't need:

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=8;i++) {
        printf "%s%s",$i,FS
    }
    for(i=10;i<=NF;i++) {
    printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:FS)
    }
}' file
```

Note: Please set your field separator accordingly. You haven't stated what it is so I am going with default (that is space)

**Sample Test: (skipping over 3rd column)**

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=2;i++) {
        printf "%s%s",$i,FS
    }
    for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) {
    printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:FS)
     }
}' file
1 2 4 5 6
1 2 4 5 6
1 2 4 5 6
```